# Only the string 'symbols' is supported for Nasdaq

Tags: pandas

```
import pandas_datareader as web
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 30)

f = web.DataReader("AAPL", "nasdaq", start, end)
```

I run this code and the result is like this

```
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py", line 377, in DataReader
    "Nasdaq, not %r" % (name,))
ValueError: Only the string 'symbols' is supported for Nasdaq, not 'AAPL'
```

so how can I fix this one please help.

Comment: The error message is telling you a lot. You need to replace the string "AAPL" with 'symbols'. If you just want the result for `AAPL`, look at the (excellent) [documentation](http://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html#nasdaq-trader-symbol-definitions) for examples.

Comment: But the Apple company nasdaq symbol is “AAPL” I don’t think symbol is not incorrect could you more detail explains please

Comment: Yes, it's the correct symbol, but Python is telling you that you wrote it in the wrong place! Did you look at the documentation I linked to?

Comment: For example, what about `f = web.DataReader('AAPL', 'morningstar', start, end)`?

Comment: It's not working f = web.DataReader('AAPL', 'morningstar', start, end)  @Josh Friedlander

Comment: And you send document link and I look through and it dosn't helpful.... @Josh Friedlander

Comment: Same error for me as well. @pathfineder did you find the way?